# How can i hide price subtotal from cart popover in odoo eCommerce website

Tags: odoo, e-commerce, odoo-9, odoo-website

i want to remove or hide price subtotal from My-Cart popover in odoo eCommerce website .. popover screenshot attached below.

[Image attached here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LzLSe.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cart popover view id is `website_sale.cart_popover`.

You can inherit it or turn on Debug mode. 
Go to `Settings->User Interface->Views` search popover view and simply comment it out.